# How do I accsess class value of an object ,vice versa?

Tags: python, class

I am a pretty newbie programmer and I recently learned about classes trying to make something simple , I want to know how I can access the instance variables of one class to another vice versa , **In the code I want the values of health of hero to be known to enemy and damage taken by Hero to be based on enemy take a look at the comment portion**. Please do help I know I should try and figure this out on my own but I tried and have no one to help.

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name #hero name
        self.health = 100 #hero health
        self.damage = 20 #hero damage
        print "My health now is ",self.health,
    def gethit (self):
        self.health = self.health - 10 #Ten is the Enemy damage value but I don't know how to get from enemy class so put constant
        print"\nOuch my health now is ",self.health

class Enemy(Hero):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.damage = 10 #enemy damage
        self.name = name #enemy name
        self.health = 100 #enemy name
        print "Bwahahah I know you have ",#want hero health of hero after being hit value of health after gethit function in Hero
mark = Hero("Mark")
mark.gethit()
jake = Enemy("Jake")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite right. You want both `Hero` and `Enemy` to inherit from some other class, say `Person` (but you can leave that as the plain Python `object` class for now). Now to answer your question, `mark` has to be an attribute (or field or class value as you refer to it) in class `Enemy`. You would need to "add a hero for each enemy," then you'll be able to access this hero's health. Take a look!

```
class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name #hero name
        self.health = 100 #hero health
        self.damage = 20 #hero damage
        print "My health now is ",self.health,
    def gethit (self):
        self.health = self.health - 10 #Ten is the Enemy damage value but I don't know how to get from enemy class so put constant
        print"\nOuch my health now is ",self.health

class Enemy(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hero):
        self.damage = 10 #enemy damage
        self.name = name #enemy name
        self.health = 100 #enemy name
        self.hero = hero
        print "Bwahahah I know you have " + self.hero.health
mark = Hero("Mark")
mark.gethit()
jake = Enemy("Jake", mark)
```

Comment: print "Bwahahah I know you have " + self.hero.health is actually print "Bwahahah I know you have " ,self.hero.health for the entire thing to work I figured it out on my own because of the idea you gave me thanks again :)

Comment: @SamThomas You could thank bourbaki properly by accepting the answer, voting the answer as useful or both!

Comment: Ah okay , I am new to forums I accepted,can't up vote cause I need 15 reputation points